# jquery click function won't execute

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Here are my codes, the first click would get some checkbox lists, and then click each checkbox should trigger the second click function to make the checkbox lists refreshed dynamically and list items depending on what has been checked. The first click function works fine and get all the checkbox lists, but the second click just won't execute when you click checkbox... I sense some stupid bugs there but no idea where that would be....

```
// functions to capture the selection of the template sidebar
$(function ()
{

  $('.sidebar li > a').on('click', function (e)
  {
    var children = $(this).parent('li').find(' > ul > li');

    if (children.length == 0)
    {
      var templateName = children.context.id;

      $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "SingleViewNew2.aspx/AddParametersToSidebar",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{theTemplateName:'" + templateName + "'}",
        success: function (data) //callback function, VIF!! all the follow up content js should be included in this
        {
          // once in the template, 1,beautify the scroll bar 2,click checkbox or radio 3,launch report
          //1
          var item = data.d;
          var sidebar = $('#right-sidebar');
          sidebar[0].innerHTML = item;
          $('.param_list').niceScroll({ cursorcolor: "##061B58" });
          //2
          },
        error: function (err) { alert("oh no"); }
      });

    }
    else if (children.is(":visible"))
    {
      children.hide('fast');
    } else
    {
      children.show('fast');
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

   $(":checkbox").click(function ()
    {
        var checkThisItem = $(this);
        if (checkThisItem.checked == null)
         {
              checkThisItem.checked = false;

            }
            else
            checkThisItem.checked = true;
            // here get all the current checked items and then send them back to diplay the dependencyva
            //var allItems = $("input");
            var allCheckedItem = $(":checked:checked");
            var passAllCheckedItem = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < allCheckedItem.length; i++)
            {
                passAllCheckedItem[i] = allCheckedItem[i].name + "__" + allCheckedItem[i].defaultValue;
              }
            passAllCheckedItem = JSON.stringify(passAllCheckedItem);
            $.ajax(
            {
              type: "Post",
              url: "SingleViewNew2.aspx/updateParametersToSidebar",
              contentType: "application/json",
              traditional: true,
              dataType: "json",
              data: "{allCheckedItems :'" + passAllCheckedItem + "'}",
              error: function (err) { alert("oh no"); },
              success:function(data)
              {
              var item = data.d;
              var sidebar = $('#right-sidebar');
              sidebar[0].innerHTML = item;
              $('.param_list').niceScroll({ cursorcolor: "##061B58" });
              },

            });
          });

})
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ is what you need to read.

Comment: Just check that out. But still confused. My problem here is that the $(":checkbox").click wont execute. But If I put it in the callback success function of the first ajax, it could work, but only once. I need the checkboxes can call trigger the click function...The delagation seems to has the prerequisite that the DOM element has to exist first?? But the checkboxes only appear after the first ajax ...

Comment: The whole point is that delegation works on `non-existing` elements.  Change it to `$(document).on('click', '.sidebar li > a', function (e)...` as the document *always* exists.

Comment: Wow...cool...will try this. Yesterday I used stupid method to change the checkbox-click to div-click as the div always exists..Thank you Rob!!